# How to determine selection status of UIButton Class?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have created a UIButton subclass that changes between images upon click. How might I go about determining the status of this selection to use as a reference elsewhere in a separate View Controller from the one that is defines this class?

```
class ClickingCheckbox: UIButton {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "yes"), for: .normal)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "no"), for: .selected)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        }) { (success) in
            self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        //self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What part of this is not working for you?

Comment: This class is working properly. But how would I be able to reference the status of the selection (which image "yes" or "no") is currently in view to change a corresponding label to to something like "label.text = "yes image selected" or "label.text = "no image selected". I was thinking I could reference some subclass of UIButton. Like ClickingCheckBox.Selected == true in an if statement but could not figure out what that would be.

Comment: You can just access the `isSelected` property outside of this class, can't you? And then you can use that in your `if/else` conditional.

Comment: I thought so but it returns false every time I print the value. "no" image and "yes" image in the view.

Comment: Move this line `self.isSelected = !self.isSelected` out of the animation code. And place it as the first line in the `buttonTapped` function.

Comment: Same result. When I print the result of button.isSelected it continues to return false regardless of which image is in the view.

Comment: How can you get a reference in another view-controller? Are you sending same button object to that view-controller or creating a new object of button class there?

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let button = ClickingCheckbox()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2 -  button.frame.width/2  , y: self.view.frame.height/2 -  button.frame.height/2 , width: 100, height: 30)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

@IBAction func onClicksButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if   self.button.isSelected {
        print("yes selcted ")
    }
    else{
        print("no selcted")
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
let button = ClickingCheckbox()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2 -  button.frame.width/2  , y: self.view.frame.height/2 -  button.frame.height/2 , width: 100, height: 30)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

@IBAction func onClicksButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if   sender.isSelected {
        print("yes selcted ")
    }
    else{
        print("no selcted")
    }
}

}
```